# Powershell sorting multiple columns and directions

Tags: sorting, csv, powershell

I've managed to get Powershell to sort multiple columns and in different directions;

```
$prop1 = @{Expression='Priority'; Descending=$true }

$prop2 = @{Expression='Date'; Ascending=$true }

(Import-Csv $BackUpDataPath"WaitList.csv") |
    Sort-Object $prop1, $prop2 |
    Export-Csv $BackUpDataPath"WaitList.csv" -NoType
```

My problem is that the Priority value is stored as string data and sorts as text so the output to the file is;

```
Date              Priority

6/28/2016 16:46  2

6/28/2016 16:59  2

6/29/2016 15:27  11

6/28/2016 16:42  1

6/28/2016 16:49  1
```

I've tried `[int]$prop1` and similar ways to change it to an integer but it doesn't seem to work.  The Line `6/29/2016 15:27 11` should be first but it isn't.  Bare in mind as long as the #'s are less than 10 it sorts fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with

```
$prop1 = @{Expression={[int]$_.Priority}; Descending=$true }
```

Comment: That worked after I put the entire section in ()'s

($prop1 = @{Expression={[int]$_.Priority}; Descending=$true })

Funny, I tried similar configs.  Just had't gotten to this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear, but it should not be necessary to put parentheses around it.

Comment: I had you use the ()'s.  With out them I got an error saying "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '=' ".

Comment: I just realized why it didn't wort.  I implemented your changes on the 3rd line instead of the initial declaration of $prop1.

Thanks again.

Comment: Ah ok so you tried to directly pass it to the Sort-Object cmdlet - yeah in this case you have to wrap it in parentheses so it is evaluated as a sub expression.

Answer (score 0):

Looking how to convert from string->int i found [int] is not reliably, so I went for another solution. Please try something like this:

```
"2;2;11;1" -split ";" | %{[int]$Numeric=[convert]::ToInt32($_.toString(), 10) ; add-member -NotePropertyName "Numeric" -NotePropertyValue $Numeric -InputObject $_ ; echo $_} | Sort-Object Numeric
```

I create an String array, and then split it, for every object I generate the Int32 version of the value and then add a new member to the input object, I print this new object and finally just sort the array by the new property.

I tried to include the script inside the hashtable for the "property" parameter for sort-object but that didn't work :(.

Hope this can solve your problem.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  DAXaholics solution worked perfectly for me.